# Image not loaded on website from sqlite database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I have to create a user profile. When the user is connected I want to have the option to upload his profile picture. User can upload his picture from his device, then the picture is saved in local storage on a directory. Then the url of this picture is saved in database linked to the user connected, but when the user upload his picture, this picture is not loaded and nothing is on screen. I make my application with React and NodeJS. I mention that an image url saved in database is like `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc\server\uploads\mountain.jpg`

This is user page in react:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useUser } from "./UserContext";

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState(null);

  const fetchProfilePicture = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/get-profile-picture?email=${user.email}`);
      const profilePicturePath = response.data.profilePicture;
      setProfilePicture(profilePicturePath);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching profile picture:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProfilePicture();
  }, [user.email]);

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("profilePicture", selectedFile);
    formData.append("email", user.email);

    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload-profile-picture", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      console.log("Profile picture uploaded successfully.");
      fetchProfilePicture();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading profile picture:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Profile Page</h2>
      <div>
        {profilePicture && <img src={profilePicture} alt="Profile" />}
        <div>
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
          <p>{user.email}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value={user.email} />
        <button type="submit">Upload Profile Picture</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

This is the code in server.js:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload-profile-picture", upload.single("profilePicture"), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send("No file uploaded.");
  }

  const profilePicturePath = req.file.path;

  const { email } = req.body;

  db.run(`UPDATE credentials SET picture = ? WHERE email = ?`, [profilePicturePath, email], function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return res.status(500).send("An error occurred while updating profile picture.");
    }

    console.log("Profile picture updated successfully.");
    res.send({ success: true, message: "Profile picture updated successfully." });
  });
});

app.get("/get-profile-picture", (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.query;

  db.get("SELECT picture FROM credentials WHERE email = ?", [email], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
      return;
    }

    if (!row || !row.picture) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Profile picture not found" });
      return;
    }

    res.json({ profilePicture: row.picture });
  });
});
```

Comment: `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc\server\uploads\mountain.jpg` is not a valid image URL. Since your users are uploading their images to your webapp, the appropriate URL would be, for example `<your website>/<directory>/<to_store_images>/userimage.jpg` .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FiddlingAway's comment, you need to save images with relative path, now you're using absolute path, and browser then tries to load them from the file system as local resource, instead of from the web server location.

You can do that by changing [multer's upload destination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage).

Change this:

```
cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'));
```

to this:

```
cb(null, './uploads'));
```

so now the `file.path` will be `uploads\mountain.jpg`

It's another subject, but you also need to make sure the file is accessible (for example, you can make it a static folder, see: [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)